# displaying sql exception in JSF

Tags: java, sql, jsf, error-handling

I was wondering how would I be able to show SQL errors generated during update, delete, select * etc in JSF.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to show the errors to the user of your web application, or to the programmer writing the application?

Comment: Sorry for getting into it late. I want to show errors for both Balusc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have three options:

1. Let the exception bubble up (either declare your action methods `throws SQLException`, or wrap them in `RuntimeException`
2. `catch` the `SQLException` and add it as a JSF message, which is more readable. The format is up to you.

   ```
   String msg = obtainFormattedMessageFromException(exception);
   FacesMessage facesMessage = 
     new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, msg, msg);
   FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, facesMessage);
   ```
3. Don't show them (best option). These exceptions would confuse the user. Instead, log them (using log4j, commons-logging, or whatever) to a log file, which you will be able to read later. Show only a generic message to the user that something went wrong.

Comment: Option 3 still needs to communicate to the user something went wrong.